# Cypress: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM

Tags: cypress

I'm facing an issue with **[Cypress 4.7.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#4-7-0)**. Below is the error code that I'm getting while trying to automate the user creation scenario on the website automationpractice.com

> The method `cy.click()` failed because this element is detached from the `DOM`.
>
> ```js
> <input type="password" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isPasswd" name="passwd" id="passwd">
> ```
>
> Cypress requires elements to be attached in the `DOM` to interact with them.
>
> The previous command that ran was:
>
> ```js
> cy.get()
> ```
>
> This `DOM` element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current commands.
>
> **Common situations why this happens:**
>
> - Your JS framework is re-rendered asynchronously.
> - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element.

**Code sample for the above scenario:**

```js
describe("Cypress demo script", () => {
  it("triage DOM issue", () => {
    const uuid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e6);
    const id = uuid();

    cy.visit("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.contains("Sign in").click();
    const email = "tester" + id + "@yopmail.com";
    cy.get("#email_create").type(email);
    cy.get("#SubmitCreate > span").click();

    cy.get("form#account-creation_form").within(($form1) => {
      cy.get("input#id_gender1").click();
      cy.get("input#customer_firstname").type("Automation");
      cy.get("input#customer_lastname").type("tester");
      cy.get("input#passwd").click({ force: true }).type("Qwerty@123");
    });
  });
});
```

Based on the searches, it was advised to use `{force: true}`, but it didn't work. Also, I tried to embed the searches within the form, it didn't work either.

Comment: If you are referring to `.click({force:true})` on `'input#passwd'` element, why are you `triggering` the `click` in the first place. The `.type` will implicitly set `focus` and enter value.

Comment: I tried it with added network throttling and didn't see this issue. One recommendation would be to add a `.should('be.visible')` or another assertion before `.type()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CypressError: cy.find() failed because this element is detached from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840493/cypresserror-cy-find-failed-because-this-element-is-detached-from-the-dom)

Answer (score 10):

As of **Cypress version 12**, there is new code (internally) that checks for elements detached from the DOM, so instead of throwing the error it now automatically does what the error message suggests and re-queries the selector.

Please see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-0-0

> Additionally in this release, enhancements were made to how Cypress manages DOM element resolution to reduce the likelihood of hitting detached DOM errors due to maintaining stale DOM references. We've updated our [Retry-ability Guide[(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability) with all the details if you'd like to learn more.